# Logic for Three-dot more options menu for web applications in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJs and  I'm developing a social media web application. Here I have template where I have to implement a Three-dot more options menu. I tried using Bootstrap menu and react Bootstrap component menu. Both didn't work for me. What is the best way to implement this feature without using a library?

I did till toggling the menu. But on click, all the menus toggle altogether. I am not able do the toggling individually.

[image]

Here's the piece of code I did:

**post.jsx**

```
class UserPost extends Component {
    state = {
      overFlowMenuActive: false
    };

    toggleOverflowMenu = () => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ overFlowMenuActive: 
         !prevState.overFlowMenuActive }));
    };

    closeOverflowMenu = () => {
        this.setState({ overFlowMenuActive: false });
    };

    render() {
     return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.posts.map((post, index) =>(
               <div>
                 <div tabIndex='0' onBlur={this.closeOverflowMenu}>
                     <img src={require('../../assets/images/more.svg')} alt='' onClick={this.toggleOverflowMenu}/>
                 </div>
                 <MoreBtn options={this.state.options} overFlowMenuActive={this.state.overFlowMenuActive} />
                </div>
             ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

**MoreBtn.jsx**

```
<div className={`${classes['popup-more']} ${this.props.overFlowMenuActive
                    ? classes.expand
                    : classes.collapse}`}>
    {this.props.options.map((option, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <img src={option.url} alt='' />
            <p>{option.name}</p>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maintaining only a single state for all `UserPosts`

To have each of these toggle seperately, these states should be moved into the component.

```
class SinglePost extends Component {
    state = {
      overFlowMenuActive: false
    };

    toggleOverflowMenu = () => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ overFlowMenuActive: 
         !prevState.overFlowMenuActive }));
    };

    closeOverflowMenu = () => {
        this.setState({ overFlowMenuActive: false });
    };

    render() {
     return (
        <div>
                 <div tabIndex='0' onBlur={this.closeOverflowMenu}>
                     <img src={require('../../assets/images/more.svg')} alt='' onClick={this.toggleOverflowMenu}/>
                 </div>
                 <MoreBtn options={this.state.options} overFlowMenuActive={this.state.overFlowMenuActive} />
                </div>
    );
}
class UserPost extends Component {
    render() {
     return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {this.props.posts.map((post, index) =>(
               <SinglePost post={post} />
             ))}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

This way, the button for only one component is toggled at a time